# How can I get final URL (the URL that will be loaded by the browser at the end) from a URL?

Tags: java

If you search some sites like `https://www.uncox.com/` in the browsers,the browser will load the address `https://learn.uncox.com/`. And when I print the response code, server returns 200!!!. Not 300 and ...and headers locations value is null.

Now my question is, how can I use Java get the latest URL (the URL that will be loaded by browser at the end) from a URL?

Answer (score 2):

The way this is implemented in the browsers (and I'm simplifying it a lot) is that the server would send HTTP code 301 (permanent redirect) or 302 (temporary redirect) for requests targeting `https://www.uncox.com/`, with the URL address to redirect to. You can mirror this process in your Java code, to follow the redirect chain until you get a result code different from 301/302. It's not a foolproof process, and requires your code to have access to the internet, but thats the only way to get a hold on this information in real-time.

EDIT: include the HTTP code 303 (see other) to the list. Either way, it's explained in a good detail in the duplicate question.

Comment: But when I print the reponse code, server returns 200. Not 300+

Comment: @Hadi check the answers to the linked question. Basically, if you use `HttpURLConnection`, call `setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)`, or it will follow 30x codes automatically. Also check amobiz's answer there, for an alternative (and, IMHO, beautiful) solution

Comment: Ok, i'll try that. Thank you so much.